# Looking to randomize different possible outputs

Tags: c#

I'm used to programming in c++ and still relatively new to c#. I'm looking to output different 'stats' for the number input. So if you input 1 then the random shuffle happens between 3 possible outputs. If you input 2 then a different random shuffle happens.

I don't quite know where to start with this. The if loop is fairly clear to me but after that do i search a shuffle list or a randomize? I was thinking of shuffling within the array. Is there a more efficient way of doing this?

```
using System;

namespace monstergame{//enter a random number of soldiers under 5 and the program randomly gives you the number you typed and their stats.

static class program {
  public static void Main () {
    Console.WriteLine ("\nWelcome to monstergame"+"\n         ***"); 

    int soldiers = GetSoldiers();

    Console.WriteLine("\nThis is the data for all [ " + soldiers +" ] of your soldiers. Their stats are as follows: ");
  }

  public static int GetSoldiers() {
    Console.WriteLine("\nHow many soldiers would you like?  \n>> your soldiers can not be more than 5 <<");

    int soldiers; 
    int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out soldiers);

    return soldiers;
  }
}

//three cases for every soldier number 1 to 5 will be randomized

//string [] stats = {"A","B","C","a","b","c"};
```

So:

*input soldiers:*
*3*

```
//array for the input 3 is shuffled through and one of the strings is selected as output so if the array for input _3_ is string [] stats = {"string 1", "string 2", "string 3"}; then one random string is output for the whole array.
```

final output would be:

*Your stats for _3_ soldiers are:*
/random string 1 OR 2 OR 3

Comment: Could you provide *some examples*?

Comment: @DmitryBychenko Sure i'll edit the post

Comment: Do you have five different `string[]` based on the number inputted for soldiers? For example, if I input `1` for soldiers, then the string array becomes `["A", "B", "C"]`? But if I input 2, then the string array becomes `["A", "B", "C", "D"]`?

Comment: no, the number of strings within the array stay constant. But there is a different array for each input. so input 1 may have {"A","B","C"}, input 2 may have {"D", "E", "F"}

Comment: Okay. And once you have the `string[]` based on the number of `soldiers` inputted, you want to randomly take one item from that array?

Comment: yes. And here is some more information for context so if i choose 2 soldiers. each of those soldiers will have [1] a random identification number (also from a previously existing array) and [2] for each of those soldiers there will be 3 possible statistics the user can get on them (extracted from a previously existing array)  User will know each soldier's statistics by inputting that soldier's identification number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a [Jagged Array](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/arrays/jagged-arrays). You'd have `5` different arrays of strings, where each one represents the possible values based on the user's input.

Then you can get the index into your jagged array by taking `soldiers - 1`, then use `Random` to get an item out of that array.

```
private static class Program
{
    // Existing code omitted...
    private static string GetStats(int soldiers)
    {
        int statIdx = soldiers - 1;
        // Bounds checking omitted...
        string[] stats = _stats[statIdx];
        return stats[_rng.Next(0, stats.Length)];
    }

    private static readonly Random _rng = new Random();
    private static readonly string[][] _stats = new string[][]
    {
        new string[] { "A", "B", "C" }, // User selected 1 for soldiers
        new string[] { "D", "E", "F" }, // User selected 2 for soldiers
        new string[] { "G", "H", "I" }, // User selected 3 for soldiers
        new string[] { "J", "K", "L" }, // User selected 4 for soldiers
        new string[] { "M", "N", "O" }  // User selected 5 for soldiers.
    };
}
```

Answer (score 1):

So, having an array, say

```
 string [] stats = new string[] {
   "A", "B", "C", "a", "b", "c"
 };
```

we want to take `3` ramdom items. We can do it with a help of `Random` and *Linq*, e.g. (assuming that all items are equally probable to be taken)

```
 using System.Linq;

 ...

 private static Random s_Random = new Random();

 ...

 int soldiers = 3;

 string[] random = stats
   .OrderBy(item => s_Random.NextDouble()) // Random order (shuffle)
   .Take(soldiers)                         // soldiers top items
   .ToArray();                             // materialized as an array
```

**Edit:** we can wrap the routine into a method:

```
 private static Random s_Random = new Random();

 private static T[] TakeRandom<T>(IEnumerable<T> source, int take) {
   return source 
     .OrderBy(item => s_Random.NextDouble()) 
     .Take(take) 
     .ToArray();
 }
```

then use it:

```
 string[] random = TakeRandom(stats, 3);
```

Comment: So would you recommend making a separate  function for each user input (which would be upto 5) and in each of those functions i put        string[] random = stats
   .OrderBy(item => s_Random.NextDouble()) 
   .Take(soldiers)                         
   .ToArray();